# USB ports on a laptop

Tags: laptop, usb

If you attach too many USB devices to one USB port on a laptop by using something that allows you to attach multiple USB devices then can that cause damage to the USB port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

overloading a USB port should not damage the port, they usually just 'shut down' and then reset when you detach the devices. that behavior occurs here at times when my iphone is dead and I attach it to a cheap netbook: it starts charging for a second, then the port gets overloaded and switches off, then comes back on and the phone starts charging for another second before another overload occurs. no damage done.

Comment: do you mean to say this cycle repeats itself and again and again and again ? then of course it would spoil something wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

No all that does is draw power and wattage from the port.  meaning that if a usb device require a certain ammount of wattage and can't get it because it's shared with other devices, it won't work. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub) out for more info.

Answer (score 1):

No.
The hub has to admit how much power the loads use, and can only give out the amount it can get form it's connection.
Some ports of the hub may not work if you try to plug too many things in , but nothing will break.